# how to add html link in php if die condition

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to add this link, with JavaScript onclick function but not using a button,

```
<a href="#bot" onclick="startApp('ur')" img src="urBtn.png" /a>
```

And It should be run on PHP POST action with the use of the following code :

```
if($_POST['site']=="mob")
    die '?';
 else
    die '?';
```

Comment: i absolutely don't understand what you're trying to do AND what fails... please clarify... maybe this helps you with the clarification: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i just want add javascript functions #bot and startApp('ur') in php's $_POST action

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. You cannot intermix PHP and Javascript, they exist in different worlds.

Comment: Can you provide your code of html-form, may be can help with AJAX

Answer (score 0):

I think you have different ways to do this.

1. 1st one is you can use PHP as follow,

   ```
    if($_POST['site']=="mob"){
         echo '<a href="#bot" onclick="startApp('ur')" img src="urBtn.png" /a>';
      }else{
         die;
      }
   ```

If not this way,

2. you can use jquery AJAX to post your form